# Oracle using sub-optimal index on bind variables

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, index-tuning, oracle-12c

Let's say you have a table, called ORDERS, which contains ORDER_NUMBER, CUSTOMER_ID, and ORDER_DATE (among other fields).  And you have one index on ORDER_NUMBER, another on CUSTOMER_ID, and third index on ORDER_DATE.

The following query is intended to select all orders that are older than the current order, from the same customer:

```
select ORDER_NUMBER from ORDERS
    where CUSTOMER_ID = :BIND_VAIABLE_1
    and ORDER_DATE <= :BIND_VARIABLE_2
    and ORDER_NUMBER != :BIND_VARIABLE_3
```

In this case, :BIND_VARIABLE_2 would be a recent date, usually today's date, from a current order.  The problem is, that Oracle seems to want to use the index on ORDER_DATE, which selects almost the entire table, then filters on CUSTOMER_ID,  whereas it is much more efficient to use the index on CUSTOMER_ID instead (since there are only a few orders per customer).

The thing is, if you do a query without bind variables, it will always use CUSTOMER_ID like it should.  But with bind variables, Oracle creates a query plan assuming that ORDER_DATE will be some random value, so ends up using the less efficient index.

How can I get Oracle to use the correct index in the presence of bind variables, without using index hints (since I can't modify the app)?  I've already tried re-computing statistics, using histograms, etc. but without much luck.  Ideally I'd like to turn off bind-variable optimization altogether, and have Oracle re-formulate a query plan based on the actual contents of the bind variables.

Edit: the purpose of this query is to find all previous orders by this particular customer, so BIND_VARIALBE_1 is the current customer, BIND_VARIABLE_2 would be the date of the current order, and BIND_VARIABLE_3 is the current order number.

Comment: Side note: you don't have to modify the app to add hints.  `DBMS_SQLDIAG.CREATE_SQL_PATCH` will do the job (https://blogs.oracle.com/optimizer/using-sql-patch-to-add-hints-to-a-packaged-application) .

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something (I don't usually work in Oracle), but why would you have `CUSTOMER_ID = :BIND_VARIABLE_1` and `CUSTOMER_ID != :BIND_VARIABLE_3` in the same `WHERE` clause. `:BIND_VARIABLE_1` and `:BIND_VARIABLE_3` would either be the same (in which case no rows would be returned), or different (in which case `CUSTOMER_ID != :BIND_VARIABLE_3` serves no purpose). Wondering if this might be what's forcing the use of the `ORDER_DATE` index.

Comment: Sorry, I mis-typed that last part -- it should be ORDER_NUMBER != :BIND_VARIABLE_3.  Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Is `ORDER_DATE` defined as a DATE (or TIMESTAMP or similar date/time) type?  Did some idiot use a mock value of `31-DEC-2525` to represent a null `ORDER_DATE` (but I would guess it is defined as NOT NULL).  Is it defined as `NOT NULL`?

Answer (score 1):

I would create a composite index on (CUSTOMER_ID, ORDER_DATE) and that should fix all your issues, assuming ORDER_DATE is a DATE data type.  And assuming ORDER_DATE should not be null, ensure the table definition says NOT NULL.  I am certain Oracle is not using "some random value" if you gathered statistics correctly.  You tagged your question with both 11g and 12c; you running different versions on different instances?

Is your bind variable the correct data type for the ORDER_DATE?  If this is a vendor application, you may need to create a function-based index on the ORDER_DATE column to produce a reasonable date that matches the format of the bind variable.

Answer (score 1):

setting up a test cases on my side (oracle 19), it's using the customer_id index properly .. so not sure if there's more to your setup.  Can you provide create statements that reproduce issue?

On another note, I tried this:
(just a small data set test) ..

```
create table orders
   ( order_number    number,
     order_date      date,
     customer_id     number
    );
    
create unique index order_number_I1 on orders ( order_number );
create index order_number_I2 on orders ( order_date );
create index order_number_I3 on orders ( customer_id );

-- fake some data
insert into orders
   select level order_number,
          sysdate - (level/5) order_date,
          trunc(dbms_random.value(1,99999)) customer_id
     from dual
     connect by level < 100000
/

commit;

-- pick a random customer to "test" logic  
select *
from orders
where customer_id = 86954
order by order_date
/

ORDER_NUMBER ORDER_DATE           CUSTOMER_ID
------------ -------------------- -----------
       95259 22-apr-1971 14:32:33       86954
       86626 13-jan-1976 04:56:33       86954
       81076 27-jan-1979 04:56:33       86954
       66946 23-oct-1986 04:56:33       86954
       61663 13-sep-1989 19:20:33       86954
       54731 01-jul-1993 04:56:33       86954

6 rows selected.

with w_d as
   ( select *
       from orders
      where order_number = 61663
   )
select o.*
from orders o,
     w_d    d
where o.customer_id = d.customer_id
  and o.order_date < d.order_date
order by o.order_date
/

ORDER_NUMBER ORDER_DATE           CUSTOMER_ID
------------ -------------------- -----------
       95259 22-apr-1971 14:32:33       86954
       86626 13-jan-1976 04:56:33       86954
       81076 27-jan-1979 04:56:33       86954
       66946 23-oct-1986 04:56:33       86954

4 rows selected.
```

Yes, I just used hardcoded value there - mostly for just testing logic.
I did run explain on this query, and yours, using binds ... in both cases, they seemed to use the customer_id index "properly".

I'd suggest trying a change in style, what does the above query do on your side? ie by just giving it the ORDER_NUMBER of the target order, and letting Oracle pick out/join the date/customer ... does that affect the explain results on your side any?

That query was written based on your explanation of what you're really after.

that is:

> Edit: the purpose of this query is to find all previous orders by this
> particular customer,

So really, the only bind value we need is customer  ;)